# Find the number of ways for choosing 3 books from the shelf

Tags: combinatorics

In a shelf there are 6 Math books, 8 Programming books and 10 Physics books.

The first question is: In how many ways can one choose 3 books, one book for each subject?

The second question: In how many ways can one choose a book regardless of subject?

For the second I get 24, because in total there are 24 books

Comment: Well, surely you can answer the second question at least?

Comment: Yes, sure the second one is easy the answer is 24, but what about the first one?

Comment: I'd put that answer into your post.  People here don't like it if the question shows no effort.  For the first question, Hint:  choices multiply.  If I had $32$ Economics texts and $12$ History texts I'd have $32\times 12$ ways to choose one of each.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. A math textbook that i have it says somewhere in a different problem that choices multiply, I get it why the choices multiply, but why "choosing 3 books" is not mentioned in your solution. Does this mean that It doesn't matter if you choose 3 books at all.

Comment: My solution only had two choices, and I chose one of each.  As the posted solution indicates, in your case, as you choosing one each from three categories, you multiply the three numbers to get $6\times 8 \times 10$. This solution is, of course, specific to the situation at hand.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose one for each type, you have $6$ choices for the first type, $8$ for the second and $10$ for the third one. Therefore, the answer is $6\times8\times10=480$.

Otherwise, you want to choose $3$ books among $24$. So, you have $\binom{24}3$ ways of doing it, which means that the answer is $2\,024$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to choose 1 book for each subject, that means all 3 books have to be different. The possibilities here are:

Math Programming Physics $= 6\cdot8\cdot10 = 480$

Math Physics Programming $= 6\cdot10\cdot8 = 480$

Physics Programming Math $= 10\cdot8\cdot6 = 480$

Physics Math Programming $= 10\cdot6\cdot8 = 480$

Programming Math Physics $= 8\cdot6\cdot10 = 480$

Programming Physics Math $= 8\cdot10\cdot6 = 480$

Add them all, you get $480\cdot6 = 2880$

This is assuming each book is distinct, ie, it matters WHICH math book you choose.

If all books within a subject are identical, ie, you are happy with ANY math book, then the number of combinations is simply 6. You dont have to go about that multiplication business.

Comment: Use LaTeX. See please my example.